# Multiple bootstrap dropdowns - menu doesn't hide when clicking between them

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here are my script and style includes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Stuff
    </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stuff 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stuff 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stuff 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Actions
    </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is clicking between these dropdowns doesn't close the previously clicked dropdown.  I noticed that a **show** and **open** classes are being added the first time a dropdown is clicked.  The **open** class doesn't seem to get removed until click on any element other than a dropdown.

This **open** class doesn't seem to be added on the examples on the bootstrap site.

I want to keep the click behavior, but also have the menu close it I'm clicking between two bootstrap dropdown elements.

Some help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify: Is the issue that when you click on say the 'Stuff' button (and leave the dropdown menu open) and then click on the 'Action' button, the dropdown menu from Stuff doesn't close? And vice versa?

Comment: your code was added as a snippet and it seems to work fine... or am I missing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up finding the issue.  There was a part in the code which was loading a very old version of bootstrap.  Removing that script include fixed my problem.